# Update existing entity

Tags: shopware

I am retrieving an `Category` entity through the DAL and change some values.

```
$randomId = 'an-existing-category-id';
$result = $this->categoryRepository->search((new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('id', $ids)), Context::createDefaultContext());
$entity = $result->get($randomId);
$entity->setParentId('new-parent-id');
```

Instead of converting the entity to array and passing it to the DAL to `upsert` it i wonder if it is possible to "persist" the complete entity like in doctrine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, you can update a record using only `update` or `upsert` method of the entity repository.

But you don't need to convert the whole entity to an array, you just need to provide `id` and fields that should be updated (not all fields).